# Check a given range of values is present in another range values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I have 2 ranges,

**range1=range(80, 90)**

**range2=range(0,360)**.

I need to check if range1 is present in range2. Can we compare 2 ranges in Python??

More Info--These ranges are being used to check ports .i.e range2 contains authorized(fixed and pre-define) ports and range1 is changing at run time

Comment: you can simply do `if minR1 > minR2 and maxR1< maxR2` right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert those 2 lists in sets and then check if the first is contained in the other like this:

```py
set1 = set(range(80, 90))
set2 = set(range(0, 360))
is_subset = set1.issubset(set2)
print(is_subset)
```